# Hide selected items in select2

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm trying to use [select2](http://select2.github.io) jQuery plugin to enhance a `select` element in HTML app. The select allow to choose multiple items.

I'll like to remove the items that are currently selected from the dropdown. I didn't find explicit solution in the docs.

The current solution I've found was to use `templateResult` option and have the template function return `null` if the item is selected. This cause `Results.prototype.template` function to set `container.style.display = 'none'` but this has the side-effect of causing the keyboard to still select those items even though they are not visible.

Answer (score 24):

Just apply this CSS.

```css
.select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] { display: none;}
```

Small Update for recent versions :

```css
.select2-results__option--selected { display: none;}
```

[Source](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1538)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to add `!important` to prevent JavaScript from changing that property?!

Comment: Really perfect solution :)

Comment: This will leave you with an empty result box, if you selected everything, and no message to the user.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38897043/2804520), provided by Hakam Fostok.

I've reproduced his answer below here for completeness:

> my solution was modified the select2.js (the core, version 4.0.3) in the line #3158. Add the following verification :
>
> ```
> if ($option[0].selected == true) {
>  return;
> }
> ```
>
> With this verification, we can exclude from the dropdown list, the selected ones. And if you write the name of a selected option, appear the text of option "noResult" .
>
> Here the complete code:
>
> ```
> SelectAdapter.prototype.query = function (params, callback) {
>  var data = [];
>  var self = this;`
>
>  var $options = this.$element.children();`
>
>  $options.each(function () {
>   var $option = $(this);    
>
>   if (!$option.is('option') && !$option.is('optgroup') ) {
>    return;
>   }
>
>   if ($option[0].selected == true) {
>    return;
>   }
>
>   var option = self.item($option);    
>   var matches = self.matches(params, option);    
>
>   if (matches !== null) {
>    data.push(matches);
>   }
>  });
>
>  callback({
>   results: data
>  });
> };
> ```

For my purposes, I was using the *select2.js* file, so I made the change at line 3195.

Comment: There is no explicit solution that I've found in the docs either, hence why I resorted to modifying the source code.

Answer (score 1):

For  versions 4 and 4.1

```
.select2-container--default .select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Works fine!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Satheez answer, this script will let you maintain the placeholder after hiding all the selected items.

```
$('.selector').select2().on("change", function (e) {
    $('.select2-search__field').attr('placeholder', 'Here is your placeholder');
});
```